# How to correctly validate custom objects in a collection for a form without database hit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a question/answer form submission where the questions and answers need to be generated dynamically.  A bit field in the database indicates whether or not this field is required on the form.  Here is the view model for the code:

```
[ResponseValidator]
public class UserResponse
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    private class ResponseValidator : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var response = value as UserResponse;
            return !(response.Required && String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Question))
                ? null
                : new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(String.Format(
                    "{0} is required.", 
                    response.Question)));
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is that the state of the `Required` property is not preserved without using a hidden element.  However, I don't want the client to be able to modify this hidden field and submit invalid answers to questions.  Is this possible without doing a database lookup for the `UserResponse`, or is that the most elegant solution?

Comment: I'd postpone that validation to last moment when database connection is open. You may also keep a cache (a simple Dictionary{int, bool} keyed by QuestionId).